# Build project blocked in svn repository update

Tags: svn, build, ant, svn-update

I am not able to build a java project with ant, and when i launch the build the process gets blocked in the updating from the svn repository:

```
    [projectBuild] ... background task: Building workspace (Done)

sub_updateView:
        [echo] Updating Engine projects from repository
```

I am not even able to stop the process the build process.
Does anyone know how can i resolve this please ?

Comment: There are no actual error messages in your question. You show the commands your script runs and the error messages.

Comment: There are no error messages, it gets blocked at this step that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved the problem adding my SVN credentials to the svnSetting tag in my build.xml file

```
<svnSetting id="svn.setting" javahl="false" svnkit="true" username="${svn.username}"  password="${svn.password}" />
```